# Font Used in OS X 'Yosemite' Version of Terminal's Icon?

Tags: terminal, macos, font, icon

What font is used for the prompt ('>_') in Terminal's icon in OS X 10.10.x 'Yosemite?'

Comment: What makes you think it's any different from the font of the previous Terminal ?

Comment: This could be it - https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font/downloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font used in the version of Terminal's icon included with OS X 10.10.0 'Yosemite' has been identified [here](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/780103/) on [WhatTheFont!](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont) as 'Menlo,' the same font used by default in Terminal's own shells.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a font from image in websites like [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Just take an screenshot of the terminal icon and look for it.

Having only one symbol, I believe that can be difficult to find out.

Comment: OK, I've asked the guys at 'WhatTheFont!' about this question [here](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/780103/?flush=1).

Comment: I got an [answer](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/780103/) at [WhatTheFont!](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), so I'm going to post that as the answer to this question, all right?

Comment: All right, that's been done, but I can't accept it as an answer for another 21 hours (cue the Jeopardy song…)